# Questions on an external raspberry pi database

Tags: php, json, sqlite, raspberry-pi, server

Okay so I need to have a server with a databse for a smartphone applications I'm working on, and there are a few requirements.

-SQL database

-Returns queries with JSON

So i had this old Raspberry Pi laying around and i wanted to set it up for it. But theres something im uncertain of, and google haven't helped me yet.

I planned on use SQLite on the Pi, and wanted to interact with it in PHP. Then use the PHP to convert into JSON, which would then be retrieved by the smartphone. 
The thing is i don't know what service i can use on the PI to make this .PHP file able to be found from another device

Comment: Uhm... what do you mean by service? You have to code it yourself... And install a webserver/php/sqlite stack on the raspberry pi

Comment: Exactly, sorry if im vague, but what "webserver" would i need to use

EDIT: just need the name

Comment: lighttpd? nginx? apache? All could be used... Since it is on the PI, I would suggest lighttpd since it has a low footprint...

Answer (score 0):

You can install nodejs by running:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm

For SQL database you can run

> sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client

Install your nodejs mysql module by:

> ```
> sudo npm install -g node-mysql
> ```

That should get you started.